# Column Resize using PrimeNG p-table not working

Tags: javascript, html, angular, primeng

hi I am trying to use primeNG column resize using **pResizableColumn** but it is not working.
I have tried using this https://primeng.org/table#column-resize . kindly help me to solve this.

```
<p-table #dt [columns]="headers" [value]="DocumentList" [paginator]="true" [rows]="rowSize" [pageLinks]="5"
          (sortFunction)="customSort($event)" [customSort]="true" [alwaysShowPaginator]=true exportFilename="ListDocs"
          [responsive]="true" [(first)]="first" [showCurrentPageReport]="true"
          currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {first} to {last} of {totalRecords} entries"
          [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,15,25,50]" [autoLayout]="true" [resizableColumns]=true responsiveLayout="scroll"
          selectionMode="multiple" [(selection)]="selectedItems">

 



<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
<tr>
<th pResizableColumn style="border-bottom: none !important;" [style]="{minWidth: '120px'}"><span><p-tableHeaderCheckbox
                style="padding-left:5px;border-bottom: none !important;">
</p-tableHeaderCheckbox>{{'Select' | translate}}</span></th>
<th [pSortableColumn]="'DOC_GRP_NUM'" pResizableColumn style="padding-left:5px !important;border-bottom: none !important;
          border-left:none !important" [style]="{minWidth: '150px'}">
                {{'Document_Group_Number' | translate}}
<p-sortIcon [field]="'DOC_GRP_NUM'" ariaLabelAsc="Activate to sort in ascending order"
                  ariaLabelDesc="Activate to sort in descending order">
</p-sortIcon>
</th>

</tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" id="table" let-documentList>
<tr>
<td>
<p-tableCheckbox [value]="rowData"></p-tableCheckbox>
</td>
<td [style]="{minWidth: '150px'}"><a id="docNum"
                  style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="openDocNumPopup(docNumPopup);Data(rowData)">{{rowData.DOC_GRP_NUM}}
</a>
</td>

</tr>
</ng-template>

</p-table>
```